# Corollary from Hahn Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a subspace of a linear and normed space $X$ and let $x_{0}\in X$.

$x_{0}\in \text{cl}M$ if and only if there exists no bounded linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in M$ and $f(x_{0})\neq 0$.

I need some help with the proof.

The first part, I mean $''=>"$ is easy proving by contradiction. Now, the other way round. I assume $x_{0}\notin \text{cl}M$. Denote $M'$ the linear subspace generated by $M\cup\{ x_{0}\}$ and consider $f(x+\lambda x_{0})=\lambda$ for $x\in M$ ($\lambda$ is a scalar). Note that for $x\in M$ $f(x)=0$ and $f(x_{0})=1$. Now, is the high time to show that $f$ is linear and bounded in $M'$. One may choose $\delta>0$ such that $||x-x_{0}||>\delta$ for all $x \in M$ - this comes from our assumption. **What should be done next to prove linearity and boundendness?**

Having this, we may apply Hahn-Banach theorem and say that $f$ might be expanded  to $X$ which leads to a contradiction and ends the proof.

Comment: Pick $x_1, x_2 \in M$. Conider $f(x_1+\lambda x_0 +x_2+\lambda x_{0})=f(x_1 +x_2 +2\lambda x_0)=2\lambda=f(x_1 +\lambda x_0)+f(x_2 +\lambda x_0)$ and as a result we have linearity. What about the boundedness?

Comment: You need two (possibly) different $\lambda$s. $$f\bigl(x_1 + \lambda_1 x_0) + (x_2 + \lambda_2 x_0)\bigr) = f\bigl((x_1 + x_2) + (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)x_0\bigr) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2.$$ Additivity done. Next, $r(x_1 + \lambda x_0) = (r x_1) + (r\lambda)x_0$ gets the remaining part of linearity.

Comment: For the boundedness, try showing that $\lvert f(x + \lambda x_0)\rvert \leqslant \delta^{-1}\lVert x + \lambda x_0\rVert$.